# Go binary file for all platform

Tags: go

I have a .go file and produced the binary file using go build command from Mac. Is there a way to build a binary file which runs in windows,linux,IOS ?

I am aware we can build binary file for each of them by changing the GOOS,GOARCH params but i would like to have a single go binary file which should run in all the platforms . Please help me out of this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Different operating systems have differences in their Application Binary Interfaces, it is not possible.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have multiplatform binaries in general. Does not matter if they are created by the go compiler or anything else.

Comment: You first have to modify all operating systems to support each others' binaries, or modify all to support a universal binary format and modify the Go tools to support this universal format. In other words, it's not possible.

Comment: Why would you even want that? Have you ever seen binary distribution of *any* software which uses a single universal package for all platforms? I think the main problem is the entry point which varies between OSes.

Comment: I want to provide the program to the customers of the software to run on their machine. They might have different platforms. Thats was why i was looking for a common file. I know how to cross compile them and make a source for each system

Comment: Can this not at least be done for Mac OS X and Linux? I thought I've seen universal binaries somewhere before.

Answer (score 4):

**No**, it is not at all possible in Go or any other programming language (the **executable** is necessarily tailored to individual platforms and architectures).

However, to **cross-compile**, some [tools](https://github.com/mitchellh/gox) do exist which do the cross compiling for you.

This [post](https://dave.cheney.net/2015/08/22/cross-compilation-with-go-1-5) helps explain how to cross compile with Golang (which is pretty easy at this point).

---

There's also a Unix StackExchange question, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/298283/177527, which explains *why* different architectures require different binaries:

> The reason is because the code is compiled to machine code for a specific architecture, and machine code is very different between most processor families (ARM and x86 for instance are very different).

The binary *also* depends on the OS, as explained here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/251255:

> **Binary Format**: The executable has to conform to a certain binary format, which allows the operating system to correctly load, initialize, and start the program. Windows mainly uses the Portable Executable format, while Linux uses ELF.
>
> **System APIs**: The program may be using libraries, which have to be present on the executing system. If a program uses functions from Windows APIs, it can't be run on Linux. In the Unix world, the central operating system APIs have been standardized to POSIX: a program using only the POSIX functions will be able to run on any conformant Unix system, such as Mac OS X and Solaris.

Comment: If course, it *is* possible using a multitude of programming languages: they just have to be interpreted (Python, Perl etc) or compile down to some intermediate format (Java, C# etc). Of course,this entails having an interpreter/runtime on each target platform, and the libraries used must be cross-platform as well, which is a problem in itself.

Comment: @kostix: I wouldn't really call it a "cross-platform binary" if it's something that needs to be run/interpreted by a "platform-specific binary".

Comment: @JimB, well my train of thought was like this: the OP clearly lacks low-level knowledge about what are different executable file formats / OS ABIs; I felt like the answer was a bit moot on stressing this very point, so I felt like chiming in and clearing this up a bit for the OP. So yes, you're techincally correct; may be I'd just like the answer to be a bit wordy on the details. ;-)

Comment: Sure I get this, but maybe a way to cross compile for all platforms and then have some kind of loader that executes the right binary for the platform. Didn't macOS do something like this for a while?

Answer (score 1):

For Mac (not Windows), you can associate cross-compilation with a tool like [`randall77/makefat`](https://github.com/randall77/makefat) to generate a "universal binary", which will run on any architecture supported by one of the input executables.

This is currently implemented in [`goreleaser/goreleaser` PR 2572](https://github.com/goreleaser/goreleaser/pull/2572), which means the process would be completely automated.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/245435/136875000-a39aa3d1-b234-4585-89fb-934e80022367.png]

Comment: small correction: its currently only for macOS builds

Comment: @caarlos0 Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.